# Android Retrofit change request method GET or POST dynamically

Tags: android, retrofit

I am migrating my Android Application from traditional way to Retrofit. It's really awesome while playing with it.

But, my application's existing functionality is that it is having a global settings page to change the request method to GET or POST requests (for server side logs while debugging).

```
 public static boolean isUsingPOST(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
    return prefs.getInt("http_request_method", 0) == 0;
}


 //Check for GET or POST
boolean useHttpPOST = isUsingPOST();

if (useHttpPOST == false) {     //GET
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
} else {    //POST
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
    response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
}
```

In retrofit: As we define the request method to GET or POST before the call:

```
@GET("/getVersion")
void getVersion(Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
```

Should I maintain two methods??!!!

```
@GET("/getVersion")
void getVersionGET(Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
@POST("/getVersion")
void getVersionPOST(Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
```

Is there any way to change @GET or @POST dynamically..I think I am missing very basic stuff..please help me friends.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both actions do the same thing?

Comment: Hi frankelydiaz, yes both actions are same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote the right answer you should keep both methods because switching between GET or POST is not a responsibility of your http client layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Hmm maintaining both methods is the only option I think :(

Comment: @Sandeep Have you been able to find any solution? I have similar requirement.